# In BigQuery can I do a self-join while ensuring consistency of the data if the table is changing

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to query A join A in BigQuery and table A is changing frequently.  I want to ensure the same snapshot is used on both sides so I never get a pair of records a, b without b, a. Any ideas please?

Comment: Under all normal circumstances, and for every DB I've ever used, data is always consistent within a query and is at the state of the data when the query is executed. If this wasn't the case then the database would basically be unusable.

Comment: Agree with NickW. The behaviour you desire is exactly how databases work.

Comment: Just ctrl+f "read" https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/transactions to put your mind at ease

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Strange that's not what I'm seeing, I am trying in BigQuery something like
SELECT COUNTIF(a.x<b.x), COUNTIF(b.x<a.x) FROM [TABLE] a JOIN [SAME TABLE] b 
and the counts are very slightly different whereas I would expect exact symmetry